# Where is the image of the man in this fan-made Captain Planet poster from?

Tags: character-identification

Ok, so I stumbled across this image recently -

[image: Captain Planet Poster]

And after some close inspection, it turns out this was fan made (Some clues indicate the Typography - the "C" looks terrible, the symmetry of the title is off, the Captain Planet logo looks too crisp against the rest of the figure, etc).

The figure used to represent Captain Planet was almost certainly borrowed from somewhere to use in this art. I *know* I've seen him before, but I can't place him. That is to say, I have seen that *exact* image elsewhere before. Where's he from?

(Without any surrounding distractions):

[image: Close-up of Face]

Comment: Are you asking who is Captain Planet or who is the character on the poster?

Comment: @Yasskier Who is the character on the poster. As I said above, this is a fan made image, so the image of the person in the middle is taken from somewhere else.

Comment: I think the C is meant to represent the planet, also I'd watch this, looks cool as, kudos to whoever made it

Comment: Using the planet Earth to represent the element earth is... an interesting interpretation.

Comment: @Aequitas The 'C' is actually just that way in the font. That is the [Birth of a Hero](http://www.dafont.com/birth-of-a-hero.font?text=CAPTAIN+PLANET) font. (Granted, whoever made this might have selected that font because they felt the 'C' worked that way, I suppose)

Comment: It looks more reasonable next to the G and lowercase e, and somewhat the v.

Comment: @Moyli As is using the sun to represent elemental fire, and a spiral galaxy to represent elemental wind. :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's Superman, from *Kingdom Come*:

[image: Cover of Kingdom Come #4]

Comment: *Snap!* Nicely done!

Comment: @Keen : I was JUST about to post this.  Looks like you're the fastest gun in the west tonight.  +1  :-)